# Print colored raw output with jq on terminal

Tags: bash, jq, ansi-escape, ansi-colors

I'm trying to print a report on the terminal. The report is JSON and I print it on the terminal as a raw jq output.

I'm trying to color the output for few values something on the lines of

```
echo -e "\033[31m Hello World"
```

but have been unable to do so.

When I do something like below

```
echo '[{"value": "New", "onclick": "Ready"},{"value": "Old", "onclick": "Stopped"}]' | jq -r  '.[] | "\n", .value, .onclick '
```

It prints

> New
>
> Ready
>
> Old
>
> Stopped

So it understands \n new line character
but I want to have something like this

> **New (In Bold and Red Color)**
>
> Ready
>
> **Old (In Bold and Red Color)**
>
> Stopped

to make it more readable

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This illustration should be enough to get you over the hurdle:

```
jq -n -r '

def colors:
 {
 "black": "\u001b[30m",
 "red": "\u001b[31m",
 "green": "\u001b[32m",
 "yellow": "\u001b[33m",
 "blue": "\u001b[34m",
 "magenta": "\u001b[35m",
 "cyan": "\u001b[36m",
 "white": "\u001b[37m",
 "reset": "\u001b[0m",
};

colors.red + "red" + colors.green + "green"
'
```

### Elaboration

```
# print $text in the specified color
def pc($text; color):
  (colors | color) + $text + colors.reset;

# Usage example:
pc("red"; .red) + pc("green"; .green)
```

Comment: Thanks @peak.I was able to form my final expression.

`
jq --raw-output 'def red: "\u001b[31m"; def yellow: "\u001b[33m"; def reset: "\u001b[0m";  .requestObj[] | select(. !=     null) | "\n", red + .category + reset, yellow + .messages[] + reset' 
`


Added reset as a best practice.

Comment: `-r` did the trick, thank you! `jq -r '.logs[].message' < my.json`